# Difference between SystemRoot and C:\Windows

Tags: c, windows, driver, kernel-mode

In kernel mode, do `\SytemRoot` and `\??\C:\Windows` produce the same result?

For instance, if I want to access a file named `test.txt` in the `Windows` directory, what is right to use between the two options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access a file `test.txt` in the directory `C:\Windows` explicitly, *by name*, you would use `\??\C:\Windows\test.txt`. However, this is most likely not what you want (unless you got the full path including `C:\Windows` from elsewhere and just prepend `\??\`), because it will fail if Windows is installed elsewhere, for example `\??\D:\WINNT` (or `\??\X:\Windows` in case of the recovery environment).

So, if you just want to access a file `test.txt` in the directory in which the current Windows installation is located, i.e. by the *role* of the directory as system root directory, regardless of its absolute path, you'd use `\SystemRoot\test.txt`. This is usually what you want, since `\SystemRoot` is a symlink that always points to the correct Windows installation directory. This even works if the drive letter of the partition (i.e. the symlink `\??\C:`) gets unexpectedly unassigned or changed at runtime (or wasn't assigned yet to begin with) because it doesn't go through symlinks in `\??` like `\??\C:\Windows` but instead it directly points to a device path like `\Device\Harddisk0\Partition1\Windows`.

Comment: To expand current details a bit, for a very long time now, "\Device\Harddisk0\Partition1" (the device name in NT 4.0) is a symlink to an enumerated volume device such as "\Device\HarddiskVolume2". Also, in Windows 10, "\SystemRoot" is a symlink to "\Device\BootDevice\Windows" (if the system is installed in "\Windows"), and "\Device\BootDevice"  is a symlink to the boot volume device (normally drive "C:") such as "\Device\HarddiskVolume2".